# Not retrieving GPS in background

Tags: android, background, gps, location

I made an Android app (`targetSdkVersion 27`) that records the GPS track as we walk, once each minute. It is intended to work while the phone is in the backpack, screen off, app in background. It worked fine until I upgraded my phone to Android 10. Now it records only once in a while, rendering the app useless. I can even see the GPS icon disappearing when sending the app to the background with the middle button.

I guess the app is updating the GPS position only when the app is not in the foreground AND with the screen on. Then making a google search I find [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background): it seems Android 10 requires a special background location permission in the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

I added the permission, but the problem persists (the location permission changed but I changed it back to "all the time"). Then I upgraded to `targetSdkVersion 29` and `AndroidX`, and the problem persists. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: Oh, boy... No, I haven't. This is why I hate to upgrade phones. I will try to see tomorrow if this is the issue, and how can I solve it. Thanks!

Comment: I am now keeping the app in background through a notification called through `startForeground()`, since I don't know how to implement the suggested ` startForegroundService()` because my app never called `startService()` but instead `ContextWrapper.bindService()`. It works now, although I am not sure about the battery impact.

Comment: By the way, you can run your app with foreground service and it should be ok. Just try it.

Comment: @IlKadyrov: I don't know how to do that when the service is started with `ContextWrapper.bindService()`. Anyway, it seems I solved the issue with a foreground notification: `startForeground(1, MyNotificationBuilder.build())`